# Linking answers to questions in a simple survey app

Tags: php, database, cakephp, database-design, orm

I'm trying to learn CakePHP by trying to build a fairly simple survey style application. However, I'm having some issues (possibly with CakePHP, possibly with my database design) trying to link answers to questions.

Within my database, I have defined:

- A customer table, which holds customer information.
- An assessment table, which holds some basic information about an
  assessment, which in my case is linked to a customer and allows
  the creator to select a number of questions from the pool of
  questions defined.
- An assessments_questions table which joins an assessment to a
  question.
- A questions table which stores the questions.

What I need to do now is find a way to link a question in an assessment with a user supplied answer and I'm struggling to see how to achieve this. In fairness, I'm not sure if my issue is my database design or how I am interpreting CakePHP.

Ultimately, what I am trying to achieve is a one page form for an assessment that the user can navigate to and add answers to the questions in an assessment. Something like a form with the assessment details, with all the selected questions listed below with a text field next to each one.

Can anyone provide me with some pointers? I've exhausted my Google-fu (it doesn't help when I don't really know what I should be looking for!).

My schema is below (ignore the epcs bits, they join some other info).

I've used Bake on customers, assessments and questions. I can add a customer. I can add an assessment and select 1 or more questions to associate with the assessment. Any advice on joining answers would be much appreciated.

Database Schema:

[image: Schema]

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to store answers to the questions in your BTM table `assesments_questions`. If so, then have a look at the [Through option](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option)

Comment: Thanks @StanislavYakubenko - That looks to get me a step further. I've added the field to the assesments_questions table and changed the 'AssessmentsTable' entry to be 'through' as opposed to 'joinTable' and I can now see the answer field in the CakePHP debugger underneath 'assessment->questions->0->_joinData'.

I guess my next question is how do I manipulate this data. I'll have to have a read-up on the 'through' option.

Thanks!